# JSONException: Not a primitive array in parsing JSONArray

Tags: android, json

JSON I'm dealing with:

```
[
  {
    "score":2.860397,
    "show": {
      "id": 82,
      "url": "http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/82/game-of-thrones",
      "name": "Game of Thrones",
      "type": "Scripted",
      "language": "English",
      "genres": [
        "Drama", "Adventure", "Fantasy"
      ],
      "status": "Running",
      "runtime": 60,
      "premiered": "2011-04-17",
      "schedule": {
        "time": "21:00",
        "days": [ "Sunday" ]
      },
      "rating": {
        "average": 9.4
      },
      "weight": 100,
      "network": {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "HBO",
        "country": {
          "name": "United States",
          "code": "US",  
          "timezone": "America/New_York"
        }
      },
      "webChannel": null,
      "externals": {
        "tvrage": 24493,
        "thetvdb": 121361,
        "imdb": "tt0944947"
      },
      "image": { 
        "medium": "http://tvmazecdn.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/53/132622.jpg",
        "original": "http://tvmazecdn.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/53/132622.jpg"
      },           
      "summary": "<p>Based on the bestselling book series A Song of Ice and Fire by George R.R. Martin, this sprawling new HBO drama is set in a world where summers span decades and winters can last a lifetime. From the scheming south and the savage eastern lands, to the frozen north and ancient Wall that protects the realm from the mysterious darkness beyond, the powerful families of the Seven Kingdoms are locked in a battle for the Iron Throne. This is a story of duplicity and treachery, nobility and honor, conquest and triumph. In the <strong><em>\"Game of Thrones\"</em></strong>, you either win or you die.</p>",
      "updated": 1462561599,
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/82"
        }, 
        "previousepisode": {  
          "href": "http://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/664672"
         },
        "nextepisode": {
          "href": "http://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/664673"
        }
      }
    } 
  }
]
```

My code:

```
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, final_url, (String)null,
    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);

                for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_object = (JSONObject)jArray.get(i);
                    String name = json_object.getString("name");
                    System.out.println(name);
                }
            } catch(JSONException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println(error);
        }
    }
);
```

I've seen there are many questions like that but most of them deal with `JSONObject` not `JSONArray` and I didn't find solution that would work for me.

I'm still getting error mentioned in title. Any help?

UPDATE:
Tried everything except gson so far and still doesn't work.
Stack trace is:

```
05-08 14:18:14.790 2628-2628/com.example.user.test W/System.err:     org.json.JSONException: Not a primitive array: class org.json.JSONArray
05-08 14:18:14.790 2628-2628/com.example.user.test W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:116)
05-08 14:18:14.790 2628-2628/com.example.user.test W/System.err:     at com.example.user.test.SearchActivity$2$override.onResponse(SearchActivity.java:134)
05-08 14:18:14.790 2628-2628/com.example.user.test W/System.err:     at com.example.user.test.SearchActivity$2$override.access$dispatch(SearchActivity.java)
05-08 14:18:14.790 2628-2628/com.example.user.test W/System.err:     at com.example.user.test.SearchActivity$2.onResponse(SearchActivity.java:0)
05-08 14:18:14.790 2628-2628/com.example.user.test W/System.err:     at com.example.user.test.SearchActivity$2.onResponse(SearchActivity.java:115)
05-08 14:18:14.790 2628-2628/com.example.user.test W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:72)
05-08 14:18:14.790 2628-2628/com.example.user.test W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
05-08 14:18:14.790 2628-2628/com.example.user.test W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
05-08 14:18:14.790 2628-2628/com.example.user.test W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-08 14:18:14.790 2628-2628/com.example.user.test W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-08 14:18:14.790 2628-2628/com.example.user.test W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
05-08 14:18:14.797 2628-2628/com.example.user.test W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-08 14:18:14.797 2628-2628/com.example.user.test W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-08 14:18:14.801 2628-2628/com.example.user.test W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
05-08 14:18:14.801 2628-2628/com.example.user.test W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

UPDATE 2:
My wole searchActivity.java Maybe mistake is somewhere else(I removed array to see if it changes anything but nope):

public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);



    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                String query = editText.getText().toString();
                //doMySearch(query);
                clearQuery(query);
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });


}

public void clearQuery(String query) {
    query = query.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s]","").replaceAll("\\s+","-"); //TVMaze API uses "-" as spaces

    doMySearch(query);

}


public void doMySearch(String query) {
    System.out.println("print if doMySearch was opened");
    System.out.println(query);
    List<Show> subscribedShowsList = new ArrayList<Show>();

    String url = "http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=";
    String final_url = url + query;

    RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

// Instantiate the cache
    Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap

// Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
    Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

// Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
    mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);



    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, final_url, (String)null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    System.out.println("print if we got to onResponse");
                    try {
                        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);

                        JSONObject joParent = response.getJSONObject(0);
                        JSONObject joShow = joParent.getJSONObject("show");
                        String name = joShow.getString("name");
                        System.out.println(name);

                    } catch(JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    System.out.println(error);
                }
            });
    mRequestQueue.add(request);
    mRequestQueue.start();
}
```

}

Comment: If you want to use Gson , i can suggest you and give you an answer

Comment: Already posted an answer using GSON. Takie a look. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
try {    

  JSONObject joParent = response.getJSONObject(0);

  JSONObject joShow = joParent.getJSONObject("show");

  String name = joShow.getString("name");

} catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it still does not work. Updated my post with stacktrace if you like to see.

Comment: Please do not use JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response); because response is already JSONArray

Comment: SOLVED. Thank you very much. Now could i ask for explanation? Why it threw my an error when I used your code (no jArray involved here) and I only had jArray defined? Shouldn't it be just ignored since it wasn't used anywhere beside declatation?

Comment: Volley gives the parent JSONArray directly as a argument of onResponse(). If you have the final response in string format then you should go with creating parent JSONArray.

Answer (score 1):

```js
  for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_object = null;
            JSONObject internalObject=null;
            try {
                json_object = (JSONObject)jArray.get(i);
                internalObject= (JSONObject) json_object.get("show");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String name = null;
            try {
                name = internalObject.getString("name");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(name);


        }
```

The show is a nested JSONObject . replace your for loop with it .

Comment: Thank you very much it still does not work. Updated my post with stacktrace if you like to see.

Comment: Solved above. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have used GSON to process your JSON response.

### Assume, we have the following model classes:

Response:

```
public class Response {
    @SerializedName("score")
    @Expose
    public double score;
    @SerializedName("show")
    @Expose
    public Show show;
}
```

Show:

```
public class Show {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    public int id;
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    public String url;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    public String type;
    @SerializedName("language")
    @Expose
    public String language;
    @SerializedName("genres")
    @Expose
    public List<String> genres = new ArrayList<String>();
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    public String status;
    @SerializedName("runtime")
    @Expose
    public int runtime;
    @SerializedName("premiered")
    @Expose
    public String premiered;
    @SerializedName("schedule")
    @Expose
    public Schedule schedule;
    @SerializedName("rating")
    @Expose
    public Rating rating;
    @SerializedName("weight")
    @Expose
    public int weight;
    @SerializedName("network")
    @Expose
    public Network network;
    @SerializedName("webChannel")
    @Expose
    public Object webChannel;
    @SerializedName("externals")
    @Expose
    public Externals externals;
    @SerializedName("image")
    @Expose
    public Image image;
    @SerializedName("summary")
    @Expose
    public String summary;
    @SerializedName("updated")
    @Expose
    public int updated;
    @SerializedName("_links")
    @Expose
    public Links Links;
}
```

Schedule:

```
public class Schedule {
    @SerializedName("time")
    @Expose
    public String time;
    @SerializedName("days")
    @Expose
    public List<String> days = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Rating:

```
public class Rating {
    @SerializedName("average")
    @Expose
    public double average;
}
```

Network:

```
public class Network {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    public int id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("country")
    @Expose
    public Country country;
}
```

Country:

```
public class Country {
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    public String code;
    @SerializedName("timezone")
    @Expose
    public String timezone;
}
```

Externals:

```
public class Externals {
    @SerializedName("tvrage")
    @Expose
    public int tvrage;
    @SerializedName("thetvdb")
    @Expose
    public int thetvdb;
    @SerializedName("imdb")
    @Expose
    public String imdb;
}
```

Image:

```
public class Image {
    @SerializedName("medium")
    @Expose
    public String medium;
    @SerializedName("original")
    @Expose
    public String original;
}
```

Links:

```
public class Links {
    @SerializedName("self")
    @Expose
    public Self self;
    @SerializedName("previousepisode")
    @Expose
    public Previousepisode previousepisode;
    @SerializedName("nextepisode")
    @Expose
    public Nextepisode nextepisode;
}
```

Self:

```
public class Self {
    @SerializedName("href")
    @Expose
    public String href;
}
```

Nextepisode:

```
public class Nextepisode {
    @SerializedName("href")
    @Expose
    public String href;
}
```

Previousepisode:

```
public class Previousepisode {
    @SerializedName("href")
    @Expose
    public String href;
}
```

### Parsing is really simple:

```
String json = ""; // Your response; for simplicity I stringified it.
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Type showType = new TypeToken<Collection<Response>>(){}.getType();
ArrayList<Response> responses = gson.fromJson(json, showType);

for(Response response : responses) {
    Log.d("Response - json", response.toString());
}
```

The most hardes part is that, your response is actually an array not object, so you have to [parse it as described in the example](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Collections-Examples).

Result of using above code:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Really appreciate an effort to present all of it in such clean and easy way! Hope I'll use it soon.

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with json and deal with a parsing error, this is the easiest way to fix the issue.

1. Look for a json validator and check if the json is valid. You can just type `json validate` on google and use a website.
2. Upon looking at the json, `name` is nested in `show`. Hence you actually want

   ```
   String name = json_object.getJSONObject("show").getString("name");
   ```

Hopefully this fixes your future issues considering jsons